# I am not able to resize manually the size of my MDDialog Box. It is the <SubTaskShowContent> in the kivy file

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Here, I am trying to view the subtasks of each task by clicking on the task item. The subtasks should appear in a dialog box, but for some reason, it is not contained in the dialog box. The box seems to be too small. I tried making the box a little bigger and including scrollview, but it is not working. Can anyone help me, please?

Here is the python file

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.list import IconLeftWidget, OneLineAvatarIconListItem,   IconRightWidget, OneLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton, MDFlatButton
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty



class TaskDialogContent(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TaskDialogContent, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class SubTaskDialogContent(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, task_text="", **kwargs):
        super(SubTaskDialogContent, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.subtask_text.text = task_text

class SubTaskShowContent(MDBoxLayout):
    pass


allTasks = {}
currentSelectedTask = ""
class MyApp(MDApp):
    database_file = 'database2.txt'
    task_list_dialog = None
    subtask_list_dialog = None
    dialog = None

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('main2.kv')

def load_tasks_from_file(self):
    file = open("database2.txt", "r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    task = None
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line[0] == "*":
            task = line[1:]
            allTasks[task] = []
        else:
            subtask = line[1:]
            allTasks[task].append(subtask)
    print(allTasks)


def on_start(self):
    self.load_tasks_from_file()
    self.view_tasks(allTasks)

def task_dialog(self):
    if self.task_list_dialog:
        self.task_list_dialog.dismiss()

    self.task_list_dialog = MDDialog(
        title="Create a Task",
        type="custom",
        content_cls=TaskDialogContent()
    )
    self.task_list_dialog.open()

def subtask_dialog(self, key):
    if self.subtask_list_dialog:
        self.subtask_list_dialog.dismiss()

    global currentSelectedTask
    print("current task = ", currentSelectedTask)
    self.subtask_list_dialog = MDDialog(
        title=f"Add a subtask to {key} ",
        type="custom",
        content_cls=SubTaskDialogContent()
    )
    currentSelectedTask = key
    print(currentSelectedTask)
    self.subtask_list_dialog.open()


def add_task(self, taskname):
    allTasks[taskname] = []
    self.view_tasks(allTasks) #just for debugging


def add_subtask(self, subtaskname):
    allTasks[currentSelectedTask].append(subtaskname)
    print("After adding the subtask")
    print(allTasks)


def view_tasks(self, allTasks):
    print(allTasks) #just to view the tasks after adding them
    self.root.ids.container.clear_widgets()
    for key in allTasks:
        item = OneLineListItem(
            MDIconButton(
                icon="tray-plus",
                pos_hint={"center_x": .92, "center_y": 0.5},
                on_release = lambda instance, key = key: app.subtask_dialog(key)
            ),
            MDIconButton(
                icon="trash-can-outline",
                pos_hint={"right": 1, "center_y": 0.5},
                on_release = lambda instance, key = key: app.delete_task(key)
            ),
            text= key,
            on_release = lambda instance, key = key: app.view_subtasks(key)
            )
        self.root.ids.container.add_widget(item)

def view_subtasks( self, key): 
    global currentSelectedTask
    currentSelectedTask = key
    print("------>The current selected task is " + currentSelectedTask)
    print("works")
    currenttasks = allTasks[key]
    print(currenttasks)
    self.show_subtasks_dialog(currenttasks)

def show_subtasks_dialog(self, subtasks):
    if self.dialog:
        self.dialog.dismiss()

    content = MDBoxLayout(orientation="vertical")

    for subtask in subtasks:
        content.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=subtask))

    self.dialog = MDDialog(
        # title=f"Subtasks for {currentSelectedTask}",
        type="custom",
        content_cls=content,
    )

    self.dialog.open()

def delete_task(self,key):
    allTasks.pop(key, None)
    print(allTasks) 


def close_task_dialog(self, *args):
    self.task_list_dialog.dismiss()

def close_subtask_dialog(self):
    self.subtask_list_dialog.dismiss()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
```

And here is the kivy file

```
MDFloatLayout:
MDLabel:
    id: task_label
    halign: "center"
    markup: True
    text:"[b][u][size=48]Your Task Manager[/size][/u][/b]"
    pos_hint: {"y": 0.45}

ScrollView:
    pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.5, "center_x": 0.5}
    size_hint: 0.9, 0.8
    MDList:
        id: container

MDFloatingActionButton:
    icon: "plus-thick"
    on_release: app.task_dialog()
    elevation_normal: 12
    pos_hint: {"x": 0.45 , "y": 0.04}


<TaskDialogContent>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "10dp"
    size_hint : 1, None
    height: "130dp"

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1

        MDTextField:
            id: task_text
            hint_text: "Add a task ..."
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.4}
            max_text_length: 50
            on_text_validate: (app.add_task(task_text.text), app.close_task_dialog())


BoxLayout:
    orientation: "horizontal"

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "SAVE"
        on_release: (app.add_task(task_text.text), app.close_task_dialog())
    MDFlatButton:
        text: "CANCEL"
        on_release: app.close_task_dialog()


<SubTaskDialogContent>:
    id: subtask_content  
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "10dp"
    size_hint : 1, None
    height: "130dp"

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1

        MDTextField:
            id: subtask_text
            hint_text: "Add a subtask ..."
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.4}
            max_text_length: 50
            on_text_validate: app.add_subtask(subtask_content.ids.subtask_text.text), app.close_subtask_dialog()


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "SAVE"
            on_release: app.add_subtask(subtask_content.ids.subtask_text.text), app.close_subtask_dialog()
        MDFlatButton:
            text: "CANCEL"
            on_release: app.close_subtask_dialog()


<SubTaskShowContent>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            id: subtasks_grid
            cols: 1
            spacing: dp(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `adaptive_height=True` to the `MDBoxLayout`:

```
    content = MDBoxLayout(orientation="vertical", adaptive_height=True)
```